# DateTime: Баг или фича?

Tags: php, datetime

```
function func_diff($d1) {
    $of = new DateTime();
    $of->setTimestamp($d1);

    $to = new DateTime();
    //$to->setTimestamp('1475107200'); // 29.09.2016 00:00:00

    return $to->diff($of)->format('%r%a');
}
```

функция должна выводить количество дней между $d1 и unixtimestamp (1475107200)

При этом `func_diff('1475193600')` (30.09.2016 00:00:00) выводит 0, а `func_diff('1475107200')` (29.09.2016 00:00:00) выводит -0

> PHP Version 5.6.24

Comment: Проверил, выводит 1 и 0 соответственно, что я делаю не так?

Comment: С кодом все нормально, работает - [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a27f91465c0dadf39aedd1615ac890287655350). Может что то с настройками, зоной, может баг)

Comment: Попробуйте удалить строчку $to->setTimestamp('1475107200');

Comment: [Тут наглядно видно](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d8aa1bb175f68abcee6c9e103fd64f48f7e8c618)

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь получить разницу в днях а у дат разница в часах:

```
function func_diff($d1) {
    $to = new DateTime("now");
    $to->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
    $of = new DateTime('@'.$d1);

    var_dump($to->format('c'), $of->format('c'));
    var_dump($to->diff($of)->format('%R%h часов'));
}
func_diff('1475193600'); //30.09.2016 00:00:00
func_diff('1475107200'); //29.09.2016 00:00:00
func_diff('1475020800'); //28.09.2016 00:00:00
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aeacabbde2993d81fcc2cfb89fa41487c73e792a)

В вашем примере вы получаете "-" или пусто с помощью флага `%r` (указывает какая разница, положительная или отрицательная). Затем кол-во дней флагом `%a`, а их 0. В итоге, вы получаете или 0 или -0.

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодится, не идеально, но работает:

```
  function kupoig_diff($d1) {
        $of = new DateTime();
        $of->setTimestamp(strtotime(date('d-m-Y', $d1)));

        $to = new DateTime();
        $to->setTimestamp(strtotime(date('d-m-Y')));

        return $to->diff($of)->format('%r%a');
    }
```

Comment: Как вариант - `$of = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y', $d1));
    $to = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y'));`